# What is the meaning of `cd =-`?

Tags: csh, tcsh

As usual, I mistyped the command

```
[csh]$ cd -
```

and typed

```
[csh]% cd =-
```

Surprisingly, this worked!

> **Question:** What does the meaning of the equal-sign (`=`) here?

Comment: Well done with finding your own answer! If I can make a recommendation, do not use CSH any further. It is buggy and should be avoided. Attempt to use a more stable shell such as bash or zsh or just stick to pure Posix sh. Take your time and read [Top 10 Reasons not to use C Shell](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) and [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Comment: Yes, I've read that before, so I use Csh only in interactive mode on my organization's workstation now. For scripting, I just use Bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is related to directory stack, which is usually manipulated by `pushd` and `popd`.

In csh, `cd =(index)` pulls out the element of that index from the directory stack, and replace the top element (index 0), which is also the current directory.

`-` as an index here is for the bottom element in the directory stack.  Or, `-` is for the previous directory if the directory stack contains only the current directory, which means you `popd` out all the directories or you are not using `pushd` at all.  In this case, `cd =-` works just the same as `cd -`.

Here is the explanation from man page:

```
   Directory stack substitution (+)
   The  directory stack is a list of directories, numbered from zero, used by the pushd, popd and dirs builtin commands (q.v.).  dirs can
   print, store in a file, restore and clear the directory stack at any time, and the savedirs and dirsfile shell variables can be set to
   store  the  directory  stack  automatically on logout and restore it on login.  The dirstack shell variable can be examined to see the
   directory stack and set to put arbitrary directories into the directory stack.

   The character ‘=’ followed by one or more digits expands to an entry in the directory stack.  The special case  ‘=-’  expands  to  the
   last directory in the stack.  For example,

       > dirs -v
       0       /usr/bin
       1       /usr/spool/uucp
       2       /usr/accts/sys
       > echo =1
       /usr/spool/uucp
       > echo =0/calendar
       /usr/bin/calendar
       > echo =-
       /usr/accts/sys

   The  noglob  and  nonomatch  shell variables and the expand-glob editor command apply to directory stack as well as filename substitu-
   tions.
```